# Complex google analytics regex on a subdirectory

Tags: regex, google-analytics, request

In Google Analytic you can add regex to a filter to get results specific to a sub directory.

I have the two sub dirs "/topoffer" and "/topoffers" and I need to regex that keeps them separate. 
The site responds to /topoffer and /topoffer/whatever as well as /topoffers and /topoffers/whateverother .

If I use ^/topoffer, the results will be included in ^/topoffers.
If I use ^/topoffer/, /topoffer with no trailing "/" gets omitted.

I tried ^/(topoffer/|topoffer$) but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Google Analytics eats negative lookahead, but try this:

```
^/topoffer(?!s)[/]?
```

if matches everything that starts with `/topoffer`, not followed by a `s` and an optional `/` at the end.

Comment: That seems to work, although my original seems to work now as well. I'll know for sure in 24 hours.

Comment: I looked at your regex again, and yes, that one should work as well!

Comment: And how's the regex doing? seeing any results?